# VBA check If dictionary exists

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am creating dynamic list of dictionaries and i would like to check if the dictionary exists (not the item inside the dictionary). for example i have created a dictionary using following code

```
Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
```

How do i check if the dictionary "myDict" exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have added Microsoft Scripting Runtime to your project through the VBE's Tools, References there is no reason why it wouldn't be created. If you didn't add Microsoft Scripting Runtime to your project you would receive a compile error as soon as you attempted to run the sub procedure.

However, if you require additional confirmation then,

```
Set myDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
if not myDict is nothing then
     'continue
else
    exit sub
end if
```